# Make button interrupt running loop/functions

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm writing a traffic light program, and am trying to incorporate a push button that when pushed will turn the upper lights red and the lower ones green (see diagram). I'm having trouble getting it to end the loop and function that is running at the time though. I need it to change the lights at whatever point in the cycle the button is pushed but am having trouble finding out how to make it work. Maybe someone could help me with this? (sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question, I'm willing to accept any feedback I can get)

Here's an image of the wiring:

[image: and here's an image of the wiring]

And here's the code so far:

```
int redLight = 13;
int yellowLight = 12;
int greenLight = 11;
int redLight2 = 10;
int yellowLight2 = 9;
int greenLight2 = 8;
int buttonState = 0;



void setup() {
  pinMode(redLight, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLight, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLight, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLight2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLight2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLight2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
//Initial starting light: starts off red
  digitalWrite(redLight, HIGH);
  
  //Note: leftmost traffic light is used for refrence
  //all other lights are based on each others timing
  while(digitalRead(redLight) ==HIGH){ 
    //break;
    buttonState = digitalRead(2);
  if (buttonState == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        redLightOn();
  } 

    redLightOn();
  }
  while(digitalRead(greenLight) == HIGH){
    greenLightOn();
    
  }
}

//create an initial red light function
void redLightOn(){
    digitalWrite(redLight2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLight2, HIGH);
    delay(10000);
    digitalWrite(greenLight, LOW);
    //pedestrial light off
  
    digitalWrite(greenLight2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLight2, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(yellowLight2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLight, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLight, HIGH);
}

void greenLightOn(){
      
    digitalWrite(redLight2, HIGH);
    delay(10000);
    digitalWrite(greenLight, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLight, HIGH);
  delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(yellowLight, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLight, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: *...a push button that when pushed will turn the upper lights red and the lower ones green (see diagram)*. The diagram shows one button. So if you press the button, it turns the red and green on simultaneously? Or if not, then what? *I need it to change the lights at whatever point in the cycle the button is pushed...* so you want it to immediately interrupt the cycle and go directly to red or green (or both)? *...but am having trouble finding out how to make it work.* Exactly what trouble are you having? What's it doing or not doing that you need fixing?

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. I'm working on one button to start with, which will turn the upper lights to red and the side lights to green. It should interrupt the cycle and change the top lights to red and the side ones to green. I have been having trouble making it interrupt. I have the lights working but the button will not interrupt whatever's happening at the time, it only works after a cycle is complete (which defeats the purpose of the button).

Comment: I think two end to end while loops may cause you trouble in your loop. Those are two district states, one of which doesn't check the button. In this car you may want to assign an interrupt to the button to set a stat, and have your loop be more state driven, avoiding the `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 tipps for you:

1. Use an Interrupt for the Button. You can find how `attachInterrupt()` it works at the [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/). A problem about Interrupts on Arduino Uno is, that there are only 2 pins for that. That means you can only implement 2 buttons using this method.
2. You should avoid using long delays in your code, because the program is doing nothing during the delay. That means that during a delay of 1 traffic light, you can not switch a second traffic light.
   Instead you can count the time using the `millis()` function and a timing variable.
3. Check out how a Finite State Machine works. With that concept and without the use of delays, you can connect as many buttons as you have free pins available.